# Can't run a custom fork of electron-builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder (20.44.4) for installer/updater functionality in my electron application.

There is a problem with it that it does not allow to customize the folder where updates are saved - it has just an method which does not support any customizations.

In order to resolve the issue i tried to fork the library, make a small fix inside and reuse it as a fork. For that i added this line to my package.json:

`"electron-builder": "https://github.com/MY_ORGANIZATION/electron-builder/tarball/COMMIT_HASH",`

Unfortunatelly, i was not able to build the app using the forked version - it gives me an error ("electron-builder is not recognized").

I also tried to make some kind of "monkey patching" (i really need quick & dirty solution for this), but i can not find a way to do such trick in node - is it even possible?